# Hibernate, joining two columns against one

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have such tables:
Table1: Users

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lastname   | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| birth_date | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_deleted | tinyint     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Entity1:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "lastname", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "birth_date")
    private Date birthDate;
    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;
```

Table2: Friendships

```
+----------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| Field          | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |
+----------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| first_user_id  | int       | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| second_user_id | int       | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| timestamp      | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
+----------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Entity2:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "friendships")
public class Friendship {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "first_user_id")
    private int firstUserId;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "second_user_id")
    private int secondUserId;
```

I have to get all the user's friends using Hibernate without native SQL queries. User's id may appear in both columns of the 2nd table. With JDBC and SQL I used this query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.lastname FROM users u
 INNER JOIN friendships f
  ON u.id = f.first_user_id OR u.id = f.second_user_id
  WHERE f.second_user_id = :userId AND u.id = f.first_user_id
UNION
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.lastname  FROM users u
 INNER JOIN friendships f
  ON u.id = f.first_user_id OR u.id = f.second_user_id
  WHERE f.first_user_id = :userId AND u.id = f.second_user_id;
```

Is it possible to do that with Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, i think your query can be simplified to

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.lastname FROM users u
INNER JOIN friendships f
ON u.id = f.first_user_id OR u.id = f.second_user_id
WHERE (f.second_user_id = :userId AND u.id = f.first_user_id)
OR (f.first_user_id = :userId AND u.id = f.second_user_id)
```

and if i'm not mistaken the Hibernate query should look like

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.lastName FROM User u 
INNER JOIN Friendship f 
ON u.id = f.firstUserId OR u.id = f.secondUserId 
WHERE (f.secondUserId = :userId AND u.id = f.firstUserId) 
OR (f.firstUserId = :userId AND u.id = f.secondUserId)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the Friendship entity to this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "friendships")
public class Friendship {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "first_user")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Userss firstUser;

    @JoinColumn(name = "second_user")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Userss secondUser;
}
```

Then you can simply use Hibernate Query Language (HQL) to fetch the data from friendship table: `Query query = session.createQuery("from Employee");`